# Symfony2 - Entity of type ...\Entity\Users is missing an assigned ID for field 'userId'

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine

I always get this message:

> Entity of type Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users is missing an assigned
>   ID for field 'userId'. The identifier generation strategy for this
>   entity requires the ID field to be populated before
>   EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
>   identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
>   accordingly.

I tried to delete:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

Or change it to:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
```

I also pasted in:

```
id:
        userId:
            primary: true
            autoincrement: true
```

But nothing works!

My UserController register action:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reuzze_reuzze_homepage'));
        }

        $user = new Users();

        $person = new Persons();

        $address = new Addresses();

        $region = new Regions();

        $role = new Roles();

        $address->setRegion($region);

        $user->setPerson($person);
        $user->setUserRating('1');
        $user->setRole($role);

        $person->setAddress($address);

        $address->setRegion($region);

        $role->setRoleName('Student');

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            if($form->isValid())
            {
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getuserPassword(), $user->getuserSalt());
                $user->setuserPassword($password);

                $user->setRole($role);

                $date = new \DateTime('NOW');
                //$user->setuserId('1');
                $user->setuserCreated($date);

                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->persist($person);
                $entityManager->persist($address);
                $entityManager->persist($region);
                $entityManager->persist($role);

                $entityManager->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reuzze_reuzze_homepage'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

My RegisterType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('person'     , new PersonType())
            ->add('userUsername'   , 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Username',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Username')
            ))
            ->add('userEmail'       , 'email', array(
                'label' => 'E-mailadres',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'E-mail address')
            ))
            ->add('userSalt' , 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'first_name' => 'password',
                'second_name' => 'confirm',
                'first_options' => array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password'),
                    'label' => 'Password',
                ),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Repeat Password',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Repeat Password'),
                ),
                'invalid_message' => 'The passwords are not identical!',
            )
        );
    }
```

Users Model (userId)

```
 /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

/**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }
```

The only thing that works is when I put **$user->setuserId('1');** in the Usercontroller register action. But obviously that isn't what I want, someone has a fix?

If I comment **$entityManager->persist($user);** in my UserController it creates all the other objects except for the User, but I don't get an error in this case.

Comment: `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` Should work - show us the actual property definition for that model? Edit: Also you need `@ORM\Id` too.

Comment: You mean my User Model?

Comment: Yes, I see you added it. The only thing that looks wrong to be is it should be `protected` not `private`. Did you clear the proxies after switching it to `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Hmm I made it protected now. And if you mean clear the cache, then i did, yes.

Comment: `cache:clear` in Symfony does not clear the proxies folder, you have to manually delete it.

Comment: the prod and dev folder? I delete those 2 folders always manually..

Comment: No, the `proxies` folder. It's called `proxies`. It should be in the same directory as your models.

Comment: The only Proxies folder I have is in app > cache > dev > doctrine > orm > Proxies and the folder is empty

Comment: Proxies are generated under cache so removing dev will make them go away.  You posted a fragment of a doctrine yml file.  You can't use both yml and annotations in the same bundle.  Remove the yml stuff just to ensure that it is not getting in the way.

Comment: And for auto increment you need: @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") or just leave the whole thing out since if defaults to AUTO.  You also have a lot of stuff going on in your controller.  Might want to make a simple test command up and test the persisting process until you understand it.

Comment: So delete all the orm.yml files in Resources > config > doctrine?

Comment: Yep if you plan on using annotations.  Or keep them and don't use annotations.  One or the other.  Not both.  If you stick with yaml then follow the example in the book on how to use autoincrement: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

delete all the orm.yml files in Resources > config > doctrine